# how to set a backgroundColor from a js in appcelerator Titanium Alloy MVC

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I have a small Question about setting Tab Names Dynamically.

I am Thinking to create an options.js and I want my tab names to gather data from options.js

```
<Alloy>
<TabGroup>
    <Tab title="Tab 1" icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
        <Window class="tab1" title="Tab 1">
            <Label>I am Window 1</Label>
            <Button class="exampleBut">Button </Button>
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

---

I would like to set Tab 1 Title from another JS file.

How to solve it ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You have to identify the tab by a unique id

```
 <Tab title="Tab 1"  id='tab1' icon="KS_nav_ui.png">
```

in the same js file for exemple index.js (the tab is defined in index.xml) you can use :

```
$.tab1.title="my title"
```

if you would set title from another js file you can use application events: 
in index file you define an application event listener :

```
Ti.App.addEventListener("app:changeTabTitlle",function(e){
                            $.tab1.title=e.title;
                        });
```

and from the other js file you have to send the tab title using fireEvent:

```
Ti.App.fireEvent("app:changeTabTitlle",{title:"My tab title"});
```